# GNU GRUB version 2.02 problem

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair, gnu

Ubuntu and Windows 8 were already installed on my computer. Then, Windows crashed and I reinstalled Windows 8.

Now, I can't access Ubuntu. When I looked at my disc partition I saw that the Ubuntu files were still there. I tried boot repair from USB and I got a GNU GRUB version 2.02 error. I can't boot repair because of GNU GRUB version 2.02 and I can't access my Ubuntu.

So how can I boot repair without GNU GRUB? By the way, I tried to access *Try Ubuntu* option, but it didn't work, because of the GNU GRUB version 2.02 error.

Comment: Does [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) work, by any chance?

Comment: yes i tried but it didn't work. i can't boot my usb; when i tried i got gnu grub v2,02 error.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what error you're getting? Are you stuck at `grub rescue`? Can you edit your question to include a screenshot? Is your system on legacy boot mode or UEFI?

Comment: i solved my problem. I was choosing the wrong options in the Rufus program. It should be MBR for BIOS or UEFI and FAT32. This solved my problem.  Thanks for all helps.

Comment: You should post an answer instead of editing your title to "solved". It makes it easier for other people with the same issue to get help.

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem. I was choosing the wrong options in the Rufus program. It should be MBR for BIOS or UEFI and FAT32. This solved my problem.